# Когда input заполнен

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добавить класс к label, когда его input заполнен.

```
 <input type="text" id="test1">
 <label for="test1">поле 1</label>
```

Как это можно реализовать на jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#test1').change(function(){
    tmpval = $(this).val();
    if(tmpval == '') {
        $('#lbl1').removeClass('class1');
    } else {
        $('#lbl1').addClass('class1');
    }
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test1">
 <label id="lbl1" for="test1">поле 1</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

В моем решении также событие срабатывает при вставке текста и без необходимости выходить из фокуса поля, чтобы сработали изменения.

```js
$('#test1').on('change paste keyup', function () {
  var $this = $(this);

  var input_value = $this.val();
  var input_id = $this.attr('id');

  if (input_value.length === 0) {
    $('label[for=' + input_id + ']').removeClass('foo');
  } else {
    $('label[for=' + input_id + ']').addClass('foo');
  }
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test1">
<label for="test1">поле 1</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

На чистом JS:

```js
document.getElementById('test1').onkeyup = function() {
  if(this.value == '') {
    document.getElementById('lbl1').classList.remove('class1');
  }else{
    document.getElementById('lbl1').classList.add('class1');
  }
};
```

```css
.class1 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test1">
<label id="lbl1" for="test1">поле 1</label>
```